# Linux mint does not remember default browser

Tags: linux-mint, chrome, browser, settings, defaults

When I launch Chrome on Linux Mint, it asks for being the default browser. I confirm and it is remembered between browser relaunches. But when I shut my laptop down and then turn on again, default browser is not set anymore.
Also, after I press *Set Default* in Chrome I can see that default browser in *Preferred Applications* is still unset. But if I set it there it is also persisted until next system restart only.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't used Linux Mint for years, but can you verify that     `~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list` exists? There's a possibility that if this file doesn't exist then chrome will fail to set itself as the default browser.

If it doesn't exist then you could do something like:

```
mkdir -p ~/.local/share/applications # use -p to create intermediate directories as required

touch ~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list # then create the file
```

Then try to set default browser again and see if that works.

Comment: Yes, the file exists and contains this:

x-scheme-handler/http=exo-web-browser.desktop
x-scheme-handler/https=exo-web-browser.desktop
application/pdf=evince.desktop;
image/vnd.adobe.photoshop=gimp.desktop;
application/vnd.insync.link.drive.sheet=insync-helper.desktop;
application/vnd.insync.link.drive.doc=insync-helper.desktop;
image/png=userapp-xnview-RWSBKY.desktop;
image/jpeg=ristretto.desktop;
application/x-shellscript=gedit.desktop;

Comment: Hmm interesting...Can you try this:

Verify that you have xdg-settings and then try something like this:

`xdg-settings set default-web-browser google-chrome.desktop`

Maybe logout and then login again after doing that and see if that works.

[source](https://portland.freedesktop.org/doc/xdg-settings.html)

Comment: Still doesn't help

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes permissions can be a problem: if one of the settings files under your home directory has ended up owned by root, then the session cannot save when it shuts down.

I think `find . -user root`, run from your home directory can find problems like this.